# switch to autologin TTY

Tags: linux, ssh, tty, gnu-screen

I have set up auto login on a machine and modified `.bashrc` so that a script runs automatically (e.g. `mplayer` playing a music stream).

Now I log in using `ssh` and `screen`. Command `w` shows the ttys used by the autologin and the current one from the ssh screen session.

```
09:58:43 up 18 min,  2 users,  load average: 0.11, 0.16, 0.09
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
mi       tty1                      09:40   18:17  30.93s  1.22s mplayer http://144.76.106.52:7000/progressive.mp3
mi       pts/1    nbg021:S.0     09:55    1.00s  0.27s  0.02s w
```

How is it possible to switch back and forth to that autologin `tty1` from within the `pts/1`? I have tried `chvt`, `ttylog` etc.. non were successful. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

thanks for the answers. Here is the complete solution for reference. Put the following in the `.bashrc`

```
if [ $(tty) == /dev/tty1 ]; then                                                                                                                                     
    screen -S autologin_session -d -m mplayer http://144.76.106.52:7000/progressive.mp3                                                                              
fi
```

then you can attach to it locally or directly over `ssh`.

Comment: You can ask at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: well. this could be any linux/unix machine. Maybe I should remove the tag. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tty1` is a virtual console only accessible from the system console. If you want to be able to access the running program from any terminal then you should run it within `screen` instead.

Comment: you mean the autologin session is itself a screen, so that the running program is started within that? can you please elaborate? thanks.

Comment: Instead of running the application, run `screen` with the application within it.